# HERE Map Image API using Bounding box get different results in comparison with OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I've tried to get a map image of area -124, 32, -114, 42. And get different results from OpenStreetMap:

[image: OpenStreetMap]

and here:

[image: HERE]

map image api. Why? and how can I get the same results?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some tasty code!

Comment: OpenStreetMap hasn't any api to get static images (as far as i know) so i do it manually. 
In Here I use this:
https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/mapview?bbox=42,-114,32,-124&app_id=ID&app_code=CODE